# Grant permission to stored procedure and action inside it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have created some stored procedures and I am trying to execute them within a web application. To endure the security I have created SQL Server users, logins roles and permissions.

Then I grant the execute permission to the rule and give that rule to a specific user. My problem is for example if I grant execution on `StoredProcedureA` to `roleA` and the `StoredProcedureA` uses a select on a tableA I got the error

> SELECT permission was denied on the object '[tableA]'

The error is easy to fix: I have to grant select on that table.

But since I am using many procedure in my project, it's hard to make the modification for each one. Is there a way to configure SSMS so that If I grant the execute on a procedure to a role, that role will have automatically all the permission on the actions (select, insert, update, delete) that are in that procedure?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you alter your procedure to include the `EXECUTE AS` clause?

Example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sprocName...
EXECUTE AS dbo -- high level example
...
```

This would allow you to only grant your users and roles the ability to execute the procedures but the procedures the ability to do what it needs to, be that select, insert, update, etc.